# Can't connect to the router when using Linux as a router

Tags: linux, router, vpn, pptp

I am using Linux as a router to filter and tunnel all the traffics from LAN through PPTP VPN,
I managed to set up the router, which is an Ubuntu virtual machine, and the client, which is also an Ubuntu virtual machine, they worked well together since then, however, the client stopped connecting to the internet when I connected the router to PPTP VPN. How can I resolve this issue? Does the router need some special configuration when connect to VPN?

Comment: Nobody answers? Is this because my description isn't clear enough? If so, tell me, i will rephrase it.